# Create high score for memory game in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have created a memory game, where the user chooses row and column in a matrix to flip a card.

The game runs on a while loop, and I was looking to count the number of attempts the user tries to finish the game.

Later I want to print this in a .txt file.

While loop for user's choice of cards in memory game:

```
while choose():

     pass
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and be sure to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: you can use a variable to store the number, just add 1 to it every time the user tries again

Comment: @reportgunner yes. but I have a while loop for the game. How do I count every attempt?

Comment: @Whatev show us the while loop, use the edit button under your post

Comment: @reportgunner done.

Comment: no good, I have no idea what choose() is

Comment: @reportgunner the choose function let user choose two memory cards. I want to count how many times it loops

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
try_count = 0
max_tries = 10
while try_count <= max_tries:
    choose()
    try_count += 1 # same as try_count = try_count + 1
```

If this helped you **please** be so kind and go read the links in Bill's comment under your question